# WizardNewFileCreationPage - is it possible to add new element

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I want to build new wizard and to extends from WizardNewFileCreationPage

I have 2 questions :

1. is it possible add new button after the FileName ? Do I need to override the create
   createControl and then to add my logic ?
2. is it possible to hide the "Advanced" button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn of the Advanced button by overriding `createAdvancedControls`:

```
@Override
protected void createAdvancedControls(Composite parent)
{
}
```

You could also create your button in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Beside override createAdvancedControls method, you also need to override  createLinkTarget and validateLinkedResource methods. Those are also involved.

```
    // Hide create link target
    @Override 
    protected void createLinkTarget() {
        return;
    }
    //Hide link validation
    @Override 
    protected IStatus validateLinkedResource() {        
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
```